# How to get specific document from CouchDB and to exports it in Jade view?

Tags: node.js, json, express, couchdb, pug

I need to get the URL and according to it do display specific document from CouchDB in Jade view.

````
router.get('/jobs/:name', function (req, res, next) {
    couch.get(dbName,viewURLSpecific).then(function(data,header,status){
var name=req.params.name;
console.log(name);
res.render('detailedjobs',{name:data.data.rows});
},
function(err){
    res.send(err);
});
``` jade view
  .row
    .col-xs-12.col-sm-8
      .row.list-group 
        each detail in the name
          .col-xs-12.list-group-item
            h4 
              p #{detail.value.name}
              small &nbsp;
              p #{detail.value.location} 

    .col-xs-12.col-sm-4 
      p.lead= sidebar

The view renders every document in my employer database. But I need to render the only a specific document, based on the name of the document, which is got from URL.
````

Comment: Does somebody will siggests some action to be performed?

Comment: remove "the" in line "each detail in the name"